# A single phase transformer has 500 turns in primary and 1000 secondary turns

Tags: transformer

A single phase transformer has 500 turns in primary and 1000 secondary turns. The
net cross-sectional area of the core is 50 cm2
. If the primary winding is connected
to a 50 Hz supply at 400 V, Compute:
a) Peak value of the flux density in the core (Ans: 0.7 T)
b) Voltage induced in the secondary winding. (Ans: 800 V)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Homework no attempt at solution.

Comment: What is your question? I see prompts to compute two values, with tentative answers.

Comment: OP asked and answered.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat Yes, OP cheats for reputation, IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

a) To find the peak value of the flux density in the core, we can use the formula for the magnetic flux density, which is given by:

$$ B = \frac{V}{4.44 \cdot f \cdot N \cdot A} $$

where:

- ( V ) is the voltage in the primary winding (400 V),
- ( f ) is the frequency of the supply (50 Hz),
- ( N ) is the number of turns in the primary winding (500 turns), and
- ( A ) is the cross-sectional area of the core (50 cm² = 0.005 m²).

Substituting these values into the formula, we get:

$$ B = \frac{400}{4.44 \cdot 50 \cdot 500 \cdot 0.005} = 0.72 \, \text{T} $$

So, the peak value of the flux density in the core is approximately 0.72 T.

b) The voltage induced in the secondary winding can be found using the transformer turns ratio, which is given by:

$$ \frac{V_s}{V_p} = \frac{N_s}{N_p} $$

where:

- ( V_s ) is the voltage in the secondary winding,
- ( V_p ) is the voltage in the primary winding (400 V),
- ( N_s ) is the number of turns in the secondary winding (1000 turns), and
- ( N_p ) is the number of turns in the primary winding (500 turns).

Rearranging for ( V_s ), we get:

$$ V_s = V_p \cdot \frac{N_s}{N_p} = 400 \cdot \frac{1000}{500} = 800 \, \text{V} $$

So, the voltage induced in the secondary winding is 800 V.

Comment: This user is posing questions and immediately supplying answers to them with no explanation as to why. S/he seems to be abusing the site.